# Is it possible to combine copying & pasting a file over while renaming it with todays date?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and still learning the ropes.
Basically I'm trying to copy last week's report, paste it in the same folder and rename it with today's date along with some text. I'm struggling with finding a solution on google.

```
Sub TodayReport()

Dim sfolder As String
Dim dfolder As String
Dim dtToday As String
dtToday = Format(Date, "dd.mm.yy")

sfolder = "\\N:\\FinanceReports\Reports\”
dfolder = "\\N:\\FinanceReports\Reports\”

FileCopy sfolder & "January - 05.16.22.xlsx", dfolder & "January - dtToday.xlsx

End Sub
```

Comment: Try: `FileCopy sfolder & "data.xlsx", dfolder & "data - " & dtToday & ".xlsx"`. Also, change the "smart" double quotes at the end of your folder strings to straight ones. I.e. `sfolder = "\\N:\\FinanceReports\Reports\"` instead of `sfolder = "\\N:\\FinanceReports\Reports\”`.

Comment: That worked! however when  try to use the same logic to open the file, it doesn't work. Workbooks.Open Filename:= "\\N:\\FinanceReports\Reports\"data - " & dtToday & ".xlsx"

Comment: To open the copy, add e.g. `Workbooks.Open (dfolder & "data - " & dtToday & ".xlsx")` underneath. With a small copy this should probably just work immediately, else maybe use a `Do While .. Loop`. E.g. `wb_exists = ""` and then `Do While Len(wb_exists) = 0` \ `wb_exists = Dir(dfolder & "data - " & dtToday & ".xlsx")` \ `Loop`, all this before `Workbooks.Open` naturally